# How to remap the copy-paste keyboard shortcuts in MATLAB on Ubuntu?

Tags: matlab, copy, keyboard-shortcuts, paste

The default keys are <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> for copying and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> for pasting. Is there any way to remap this to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> for copying and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> for pasting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Go to Preferences -> Keyboard.
There you will find "Command Window keybindings" and "Editor/Debugger" keybindings.
These are most likely set to "Emacs" style for you -- you should change them to "Windows" style to copy and paste with Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V, respectively.

Source: http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2007/05/11/setting-up-keybindings-for-the-command-window-and-editor/

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab version R2020a, you can change the keyboard shortcuts by following these steps:

- Go to `Home` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts`
- Change the `Active Settings` to `Windows Default Set`
- Apply the changes by clicking on `Apply` and then `Ok`

It will look like this screenshot.

[image: Changing keyboard shortcut in Matlab]

Now you can use `ctrl-C` / `ctrl-V` to copy / paste as usual.